# Look up and Synonyms are not working in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

I have used lookup table and synonyms, but the entities mentioned in the lookup are not detected by RASA, neither synonyms worked.

```
nlu:
- intent: place_order
  examples: |
    - wanna [large](size) shoes for husky
    - need a [small](size) size [green](color) boots for pupps
    - have [blue](color) socks
    - would like to place an order

- lookup: size
  examples: |
    - small
    -medium
    -large

- synonym: small
  examples: |
    - small
    - s
    - tiny

- synonym: large
  examples: |
    - large
    - l
    - big

- synonym: medium
  examples: |
    - medium
    - m
    - average
    - normal

- lookup: color
  examples: |
    - black
    - blue
    - white
    - red
    - green
    - orange
    - yellow
    - purple
```

It works correctly for "I would like to place an order for **large** **blue** shoes" , but if the input is "medium"(which is the lookup table) instead , it wont recognize

it wont work if synonyms of "large" like "big" is used.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found out using RegexEntityExtractor in pipeline will resolve the issue of lookup table

```
name: RegexEntityExtractor
```

But still it didn't resolved the problem of synonyms, and by default it was using DIETClassifier (which i think is pretty good intent and entity extractor) and the output of RegexEnityExtractor collided when I used it along with it.

Can someone suggest an Extractor or combination of extractor (intent and entity) such that it works well with lookup and synonyms without any conflicts?

Comment: do you have EntitySynonymMapper in your pipeline ?

Comment: yes, earlier i didn't mention the examples in lookup table in synonym mapper, i thought we have to mention only the entity names in synonym mapper and not the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try slot mapping. I think synonyms works at slot mapping.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).